# How to do form validation for my website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a registration form page of my app but i want to validate the form before sending it to the next page. this is the form.

```
<form action="jobinpal_process.php?account=ceo" method="post">
                    <ul>
                        <img src="../img/step1ceo.png.png" id="jp_ceo_img_reg">
                        <label id="jp_ceo_reg_label">CEO registration </label>
                        <hr id="suck"></hr>
                        <li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_name"><input type="text" placeholder="name" name="jobinpal_ceo_name" id="jp_n"></li>
                        <li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_mname"><input type="text" placeholder="middlename" name="jobinpal_ceo_middlename" id="jp_m"></li>
                        <li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_lnamex"><input type="text" placeholder="lastname" name="jobinpal_ceo_lastname" id="jp_l"></li>
                        <li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_sex">
                        <!--<input type="text" placeholder="sex" name="jobinpal_ceo_sex">-->
                        <select id="jp_s">
                            <option value= default selected  >Sex</option>
                            <option>Male</option>
                            <option>Female</option>
                            <option>Others</option>
                        </select>
                        </li>
                        <!--<li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_title"><input type="text" placeholder="title" name="jobinpal_ceo_title"></li>-->
                        <li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_email"><input type="text" placeholder="email" name="jobinpal_ceo_email" id="jp_e"></li>
                        <li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_country"><input type="text" placeholder="country" name="jobinpal_ceo_country" id="jp_c"></li>
                        <!--<li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_state"><input type="text" placeholder="state" name="jobinpal_ceo_state"></li>-->
                        <li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_phone"><input type="text" placeholder="phone" name="jobinpal_ceo_phone" id="jp_p"></li>
                        <li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_cname"><input type="text" placeholder="company name" name="jobinpal_ceo_cname" id="jp_cn"></li>
                        <input type="hidden" value="ceo" name="jobinpal_account">
                        <li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_password"><input type="text" placeholder="password" name="jobinpal_ceo_password" id="jp_p"></li>
                        <li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_cpassword"><input type="text" placeholder="confirm password" name="jobinpal_ceo_cpassword" id="jp_pp"></li>
                        <li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_submit"><button type="submit" name="jobinpal_ceo_sub" id="jp_sub">Job in</button></li>

                    </ul>


                </form>
```

the compulsory fields are

- the name
- the lastname
- the sex
- the email
- the country
- the phone
- the password

the validation will be based on this if the compulsory fields are zero it show pop an error, the email field is not an email also an error should pop out, if the password length  must be 8 and contain uppercase and lowercase characters.

Comment: Haven't you tried anything, even a google search can show you different ways of doing validations, here at SO you can find so many questions already answered. simple of them is the `required` attribute.

Comment: You got some invalid HTML there.. A childNode of `ul` should be `li`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of what you want to achieve, i used jquery validation plugin, and added some custom validation functions (for password for example)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.validator.addMethod('vpassword', function(value, element) {
 return this.optional(element) || value.match(/[a-z]/) && value.match(/[A-Z]/);
 }, "Invalid password format, password must be 8 characters and contain uppercase and lowercase");
jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectcheck', function (value) {
    return (value != '0');
}, "sex required");

 $("#contact-form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        jobinpal_ceo_name: "required",
        jobinpal_ceo_middlename: "required",
        jobinpal_ceo_lastname: "required",
        jobinpal_ceo_country: "required",
        jobinpal_ceo_phone: "required",
        select: {
            required: true,
            selectcheck: true
        },
        jobinpal_ceo_email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        jobinpal_ceo_password: {
            minlength: 8,
            vpassword: true
        },
        jobinpal_ceo_cpassword : {
                minlength : 8,
                vpassword: true,
                equalTo : "#jobinpal_ceo_password"
            }
    }
});
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUwUV/)

Comment: this place in the (equalTo : "#jobinpal_ceo_password") i am having issues with it is just telling me this ("Please enter the same value again.") when the password value is equal to confirm password.. http://jsfiddle.net/ubilli/8kzag/

Answer (score 0):

Use a [jQuery validation plugin](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation).

Nobody will write the code for you. However, you can use the below code as a reference when implementing validation on your website.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        // Remove red borders on click
        var $FORM = $("#registration-form");

        $FORM.validate({
            rules: {
                username: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                first_name: "required",
                last_name: "required",
                city: "required",
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                },
                password_confirm: {
                    equalTo: $("#password")
                }
            },
            messages: {
                username: "Please choose a username",
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter your e-mail address",
                    email: "Please provide a valid e-mail address"
                },
                first_name: "Please enter your first name",
                last_name: "Please enter your last name",
                city: "Please select a city",
                password: {
                    required: "Please enter a password",
                    minlength: "The password must be at least 8 characters long"
                },
                password_confirm: {
                    required: "Please enter the password again",
                    equalTo: "The passwords do not match"
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                // Do stuff...
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a java script function to validate your fields while submitting your form. Java Script function can be called by replacing

```
<li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_submit"><button type="submit" name="jobinpal_ceo_sub" id="jp_sub">Job in</button></li>
```

by

```
<li id="jobinpal_ceo_reg_submit"><button type="submit" name="jobinpal_ceo_sub" id="jp_sub" onClick="javascript: return yourfunction()">Job in</button></li>
```

Then your java script have the function

```
function yourfunction()
{
     if (document.getElementById('jobinpal_ceo_reg_name').value=="") {
        alert("Please enter your name");
        return false;
      }
      if (document.getElementById('jobinpal_ceo_reg_mname').value=="") {
         alert("Please enter your middle name");
          return false;

       }  

    // Like this , you can validate what you want
    //Hope this helps
}
```

Comment: can you write an example of the yourfunction()